# Multiplicity of the Eigenvalues of $I-uv^{T}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am struggling with determining the algebraic and geometric multiplicity of $I-uv^{T}$. with $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\backslash\{0\}$ I managed to calculate the eigenvalue of this matrix and I got $\lambda_{1}=1$ and $\lambda_{2}=1+v^{T}u$ but how do I know which one of them has an algebraic multiplicity of $n-1$?

Comment: Just asking out of curiosity: How did you get the eigenvalues without finding the eigenspaces...?

Comment: The second eigenvalue might end up being equal to the first eigenvalue if $v^{T}u=0$ but how do you count the algebraic multiplicity for $\lambda_{1}=1$ and determine its $n-1$?

Comment: 1. You should consider editing the post and adding these calculations to your post itself, it shows the effort you've put. 2. Why must one of them have algebraic multiplicity $n - 1$? There are many other possibilities: (a) there could be more eigenvalues, (b) the algebraic multiplicities may not sum up to $n$ even with more eigenvalues (if we are working in $\Bbb R$), (c) even if they do sum up to $n$, the distribution could be different.

Comment: I believe the spectrum is only composed of these two eigenvalues, I had assumed that the algebraic multiplicity is $n-1$ I tried an example of a matrix $I-uv^{T}$ with $u$ having $0$ only on its first entry and $v^{T}$ is the first row of the identity matrix $I$ and what I got was a triangular matrix with $1$s all over the diagonal. @AryamanMaithani

Comment: Also, I don't quite follow your calculations for calculating the other eigenvalue. ($\det(1 - \lambda)$?) Here's one way of seeing that what you suggest is an eigenvalue directly by producing an eigenvector, namely $u$: $$(I - uv^\top)u = u - uv^\top u = u - (v^\top u) u = (1 - v^\top u)u.$$
(In the middle equality, I use the fact that $v^\top u = \langle v, u \rangle$ is a scalar.)

Comment: Actually, after making my comment I realise that you've gotten a different sign. I don't see any error in my calculations, do you?

Comment: Indeed your calculation are correct $\lambda=1-v^{T}u$

Comment: How do you get $$\det(I-(1-\lambda)^{-1}uv^{\top})=1-(1-\lambda)^{-1}v^{\top}u?$$

Comment: It is a general rule that $${\displaystyle \det \left({A} +{uv} ^{\textsf {T}}\right)
=\left(1+{v} ^{\textsf {T}}{A} ^{-1}{u} \right)\,\det \left({A} \right)\,.} $$ @AryamanMaithani

Comment: Oh, I see. I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $v \neq \bf 0$, the space $\{v\}^\perp$ has dimension $n - 1$. (Here, I'm using the standard inner product on $\Bbb R^{n \times 1}$ defined as $\langle x, y \rangle = x^\top y$.)

Thus, there are $n - 1$ linearly independent vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_{n - 1}$ which are orthogonal to $v$. For each such vector, note that $$(I - uv^\top)v_i = Iv_i - 
u\underbrace{v^\top v_i}_{=0} = v_i.$$
Thus, $v_1, \ldots, v_{n - 1}$ are all eigenvectors with eigenvalue $1$.

So at least in case that $1 \neq 1 - v^\top u$, you are done since we have shown that the former has geometric multiplicity $n - 1$. This lets us conclude that $1$ has algebraic multiplicity $n - 1$, whereas $1 - v^\top u$ has algebraic multiplicity $1$.

---

Note: Here's how one can see that $1 - v^\top u$ is an eigenvalue:

$$(I - uv^\top)u = u - uv^\top u = u - (v^\top u) u = (1 - v^\top u)u.$$
(In the middle equality, I use the fact that $v^\top u = \langle v, u \rangle$ is a scalar.)

Since $u \neq 0$, we see that $1 - v^\top u$ is an eigenvalue with $u$ as an eigenvector.